# How to Download MY Created iPhone apps for free from app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've created few apps and want to download them to my iPhone. Do i have to use Xcode to run all my previously created projects? or is there a way to tell app store that i developed these apps so i can download them for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a voucher via iTunes connect and redeem it with App store.